Zooming on Canvas doesn’t work when resizing the canvas and updating scrollbars positions
I’m trying to implement zoom functionality on a canvas element where:

The zoom should be centered on the mouse cursor.
The canvas should scale properly.
The scrollbars should update to reflect the new zoomed-in size.

However, when I try to update the canvas size and scrollbar positions after zooming, the zoom no longer behaves as expected. The content shifts and the scrollbars do not update correctly.


let canvas;
let ctx;
let originalCanvasHeight, originalCanvasWidth;

setTimeout(() => {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  originalCanvasWidth = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  originalCanvasHeight = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  console.log(originalCanvasHeight)
  ctx.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 40, 40)

}, 2000)

let scale = 1;
const scaleOffset = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}

const zoom = (e) => {

  const mousex = 70
  const mousey = 70

  const zoomStep = 0.5
  const targetScale = scale + (e.deltaY > 0 ? -zoomStep : zoomStep)
  console.log(targetScale)
  const scaleChangeFactor = parseFloat((targetScale / scale).toFixed(2))


  // Adjust offsets so that the zoom centers on the mouse position
  scaleOffset.x = parseFloat(
    (mousex - (mousex - scaleOffset.x) * scaleChangeFactor).toFixed(2),
  )
  scaleOffset.y = parseFloat(
    (mousey - (mousey - scaleOffset.y) * scaleChangeFactor).toFixed(2),
  )

  canvas.width = originalCanvasWidth * targetScale
  canvas.height = originalCanvasHeight * targetScale

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
  ctx.translate(scaleOffset.x, scaleOffset.y)
  ctx.scale(targetScale, targetScale)
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 40, 40);

  scale = targetScale;
}
.canvas-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.canvas {
  min-height: calc(100% - 10px);
  /* to avoid rounding issue related to fractional pixels calculation */
  min-width: 100%;
  /* to avoid rounding issue related to fractional pixels calculation */
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .08) 11px), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .08) 11px);
  background-size: 11px 11px, 11px 11px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid green;
  height: 100%;
}
<button onClick="zoom(event)">Zoom</button>
<div ref="canvasContainer" class="canvas-container">
  <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>



The Issue:

Zooming not centered: After resizing the canvas or updating scrollbars, the zoom does not stay centered on the mouse position.

Scrollbars not updating: I’ve tried to update the scroll position using the scrollLeft and scrollTop values, but they don’t seem to adjust to the zoom correctly.

Canvas resizing breaks zoom: When I resize the canvas dynamically, the zooming behavior is disrupted, and I lose the proper focus around the mouse.


Expected Behavior:

Zooming behavior: The zoom should stay centered on the mouse position.

Canvas and Scrollbar updates: The canvas should be transformed, and the scrollbars should move according to the zoomed content.

No resizing needed: I don’t want to resize the canvas directly. I want the transformations to handle the zoom.


So globally I'm trying to reproduce figma workshop behaviour.
I have tried many approaches but to no avail, I wonder what I am missing
Why does the zooming behavior stop working when I resize the canvas and update the scrollbars? How can I keep the zoom centered around the mouse and properly update the scrollbars without causing unexpected behavior ?
NB: I simulate the mouse position, which is located at the center of the rectangle, because I trigger the zoom with a button click.
note that when I comment out the resizing of the canvas and the replacement of the scrollbars, the zoom works, but this is not the expected behavior

They key is to use ctx.translate() and ctx.scale() to have transformations applied to the canvas with out resizing the actual canvas. and then manually adjusting the scroll position to keep the zoom centered on the mouse pos.
let canvas, ctx;
let originalCanvasWidth, originalCanvasHeight;

setTimeout(() => {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  originalCanvasWidth = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  originalCanvasHeight = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 40, 40);
}, 2000);

let scale = 1;
let offsetX = 0;
let offsetY = 0;

const zoom = (e) => {
  const canvasContainer = document.querySelector(".canvas-container");
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Simulated mouse position at the center of the rectangle
  const mousex = 70; // Simulated X coordinate
  const mousey = 70; // Simulated Y coordinate

  // Calculate the position relative to the canvas's top left corner
  const mouseXRelative = mousex - rect.left + canvasContainer.scrollLeft;
  const mouseYRelative = mousey - rect.top + canvasContainer.scrollTop;

  // Zoom in or out
  const zoomStep = 0.1;
  const direction = e.deltaY > 0 ? -zoomStep : zoomStep;
  const newScale = scale + direction;
  if (newScale < 0.1) return; // Prevent negative or too small scale

  // Calculate scaling factor
  const scaleFactor = newScale / scale;

  // Adjust offsets to center zoom on the mouse position
  offsetX = mouseXRelative - (mouseXRelative - offsetX) * scaleFactor;
  offsetY = mouseYRelative - (mouseYRelative - offsetY) * scaleFactor;

  // Apply transformations
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // Reset transformation matrix
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
  ctx.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
  ctx.scale(newScale, newScale);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 40, 40);

  // Adjust the container's scroll position to reflect zoom changes
  canvasContainer.scrollLeft = offsetX * scaleFactor;
  canvasContainer.scrollTop = offsetY * scaleFactor;

  // Update scale
  scale = newScale;
};

// Event listener for zoom (e.g., wheel event)
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", zoom);

Make sure that canvas has the correct css props to have the scrollbars and that scrollLeft and scrollTop are updated based on the transformed content.
